# Redirect to an external url and send data as body params using express and react

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern, payumoney

I have a **form** in the frontend which post it's data to the **API** in the backend. Then, I add additional parameters i.e. private keys to it and make a **JSON object**. After this, I have to redirect to an external URL(Payumoney) while passing the JSON object to make a payment.

I can't add the data as query parameters as it contains sensitive information.

*App.js (form)*

```
<form action="/api/payumoney" method="POST">
    <label>
      FirstName:
      <input type="text" name="firstname" onChange={handleChange} value={formValue.firstname} />
    </label>
    <label>
      TxnID:
      <input type="text" name="txnid" onChange={handleChange} value={formValue.txnid} />
    </label>
    <label>
      Amount:
      <input type="text" name="amount" onChange={handleChange} value={formValue.amount} />
    </label>
    <label>
      ProductInfo:
      <input type="text" name="productinfo" onChange={handleChange} value={formValue.productinfo} />
    </label>
    <label>
      Email:
      <input type="email" name="email" onChange={handleChange} value={formValue.email} />
    </label>    

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </form>
```

*index.js*

```
app.post("/api/payumoney", urlencodedParser, (req,res) => {

    const pd = req.body;  //JSON Object that we've to parse to the external URL
    const url = "https://sandboxsecure.payu.in/_payment";

    //Here goes something that can redirect to the URL and pass the JSON object
 }
```

*index.js* (using request) -- It does the job of redirection and passing the data to it but the payment feature doesn't work
(image attached)

```
app.post("/api/payumoney", urlencodedParser, (req,res) => {

    const pd = req.body;  //JSON Object that we've to parse to the external URL
    const url = "https://sandboxsecure.payu.in/_payment";
    request.post({
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'Accept': 'application/json'
      },
      uri: 'https://sandboxsecure.payu.in/_payment', //Testing URL
      form: pd,
    }, function (error, httpRes, body) {
      if (error){
        console.log("Error",error);
        res.status(400).json(
            {
                status: false, 
                message: error
            }
        );
     }
      if (httpRes.statusCode === 200) {
          res.send(body);
      } else if (httpRes.statusCode >= 300 && httpRes.statusCode <= 400) {
          res.redirect(httpRes.headers.location.toString());
          console.log("error 300 and 400");
    }
 })
}
```

After using request to parse data and redirect to Payumoney URL :

[image: payuMoney payment website error]

I'm using proxy to have the same origin for both client and server endpoints.

Thank you!

Comment: What is the exact problem here? Are you sure that your request is built correctly? What does the API specify?

Comment: The exact problem is that I've to redirect to the PayuMoney URL along with body parameters. But i can't send this request from the frontend. So, the forms sends the data to the api and then the api has to redirect it and send body params. But I'm not able to achieve it. I tried to send a post request using "request" which I've mentioned in the question, but it didn't work.

Comment: I think you didn't quite understand my question:) What does the PayuMoney API specify? Are you sure the request has to be sent as `application/json`? Do you have a link to the documentation?

Comment: It's solved, I used an outdated url for txn. The new URL is test.payu.in/_payment. Thanks!!